# Query the database in foreach results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I'm trying to build a webpage with simple status posts. I've created foreach loop to query the database and load all the posts:

```
 <?php
 $user_id = Check::isLoggedIn();
 $dbstories = DB::query('SELECT * FROM stories WHERE user_id=:user_id ORDER BY story_time DESC', array(':user_id'=>$user_id));
 $post_story = "";
 foreach($dbstories as $story) {

  ?>

  <div>
    <article>
        <div>
          <a href="profile.php">
            <?php
              // to pull user first name
              $user_first = DB::query('SELECT user_first FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id', array(':user_id'=>$user_id))[0]['user_first'];
              echo $user_first;
             ?>
          </a>
          <div>
            <time>
              <?php
               // to pull post datetime
               $post_time = $story['story_time'];
               echo '<time class="timeago" datetime="' . $post_time . '"></time>';
              ?>
            </time>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      // to pull post contents
      $post_story = $story['story_body'];
      if (strlen($post_story) <= 25) {
        echo '<h3>' . $post_story . '</h3>';
      } else {
        echo '<p>' . $post_story . '</p>';
      }
      ?>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <svg class="thunder-icon"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#thunder-icon"></use></svg>
            <span>
              <?php
               // to pull number of likes
               $post_likes = $story['story_likes'];
               echo $post_likes;
              ?>
            </span>
          </a>
          <!-- the same for comments and shares number goes here -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>

        <!-- This form over here should pull the story_id which is the post ID from the database like the other queries up there and post it next to the url then that will allow me to use it in isset($_GET['story_id']) and trigger a query to increment likes -->


        <form action="stories.php?post_id=<?php $post_id = $story['story_id']; echo $post_id; ?>" method="post" id="like_story">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-control" id="post_like">
          <svg class="like-post-icon"><use xlink:href="icons/icons.svg#thunder-icon"></use></svg>
          </a>
        </form>
        <!-- the same for comment and share goes here -->
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
 <?php 
  }
   ?>
```

*Please read the comments within the code

Everything works fine but, I still cant get each post's ID linked to the like button (like_story). It only access the most recent post's ID.

Any workaround to reference the post ID (story_id)?

Comment: Hint: You can use SQL's INNER JOIN to optimize.. then you don't have to do the query in the loop.

Comment: So the issue is in the `<form>` at the bottom of your code?  Print the produced HTML (view source in the browser).  Does it make sense?  Does your `SELECT *` return a field called story_id like you expect?  You could just `echo $story['story_id'];` directly without assigning it to a new variable.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Nice suggestion, I will consider it if this didn't work out.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks, the form is to trigger the php as I can't do it with the anchor alone but the issue is unrelated to it. SELECT * works fine and story_id is one of the database rows it is pulling along with others above. The variable $post_id is just to keep me tracking the code in one format, as you said it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Right, the problem is that every `<form>` has the same post_id value?  Then print your $story every time you read another line from the SQL results and ensure `$story['story_id']` does change.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I would use ajax instead of a form. With ajax the user stays on the same site. With a form the user will land on a new page.

Comment: @Nic3500 you've shed the light to an important issue I didn't notice actually. As I'm getting the same post ID for every post I also get the same form ID too. **The main problem is** the values does change within the 'foreach' loop but after it doesn't if I tried to query again. I'm trying to find a solution to stick the 'story_id' to the post or the like button upon triggering the 'foreach' loop. Am I thinking right?

Comment: @Cashbee I'm using queries and submission at the moment but you're absolutely right I should, I'm just leaving it for later advanced enhancement because I'm not very good at ajax yet.

Comment: **SOLUTION** @Nic3500 **You were right** (Y) now it is perfectly working. I had to nest `story_id` in `<form>` and `<a>` IDs and used it as a reference using `$_GET` . The final code then becomes `<form action="stories.php?post_id=<?php echo $story['story_id']; ?>" method="post" id="post<?php echo $story['story_id']; ?>">
               <a href="php/like.php?post_id=<?php echo $story['story_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-control" name="do_like<?php echo $story['story_id']; ?>">Like</a></form>`